# Entity Framework insert byte[] in mysql as MEDIUMBLOB not working over 8kb

Tags: mysql, arrays, entity-framework-core, blob

So, as the title says, i'm working with .net 6 and entity framework 6 to try and insert a byte[] as a blob in mysql (8.0.26).

And it works for small images, but as soon as I go over 8kb EF inserts an empty blob instead.

So the follow will insert in my db:

```
component.Image = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File).Take(8000).ToArray();
```

The next line will not:

```
component.Image = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File).Take(8001).ToArray();
```

My db should be ok because I can insert a blob larger than 8kb myself:

```
UPDATE `db`.`table`
SET
`Image` = FROM_BASE64("mylargebase64string")
WHERE Id = 1;
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: ...why are you using Base64 _at all_? That's very wasteful and inefficient. _There is no legitimate reason for using Base64 for encoding things like images_: not in JavaScript, not in C#, and especially not in databases.

Comment: Probably bug or limitation with official provider. Try to use `Pomelo` driver instead, which is based on much mature `MySqlConnector`.

Comment: did you work this out? I've got the same issue ! ps. @Dai, from the looks of it, he's converting *from* base64, not storing the image as b64

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - your suggestion worked for me. I changed my provider to Pomelo's and now it updates blobs correctly :-) thanks